# supplying the right image size when not knowing what the size will be at runtime

Tags: ios, image, uiimageview, uicollectionview, image-resizing

I am displaying a grid of images (3rows x 3 columns) in collection view. Each image is a square and its width is determined to be 1/3 of collectionView's width. Collection view is pinned to left and right margin of the mainView.

I do not know what the image height and width will be at runtime, because of different screen sizes of various iPhones. For example each image will be 100x100 display pixels on 5S, but 130x130 on 6+. I was advised to supply images that exactly matches the size on screen. Bigger images often tend to become pixelate and too sharp when downsized. How does one tackle such problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual solution is to supply three versions, for single-, double-, and triple-resolution screens, and downsize in real time by redrawing with `drawInRect` into a graphics context when the image is first needed.

> I do not know what the image height and width will be at runtime, because of different screen sizes of various iPhones. For example each image will be 100x100 display pixels on 5S, but 130x130 on 6+

Okay, so your first sentence is a lie. The second sentence proves that you *do* know what the size is to be on the different screen sizes. Clearly, if I tell you the name of a device, you can tell me what you think the image size should be. So, if you don't want to downscale a larger image at runtime because you don't like the resulting quality, simply supply actual images at the correct size and resolution for every device, and use the correct image on the actual device type you find yourself running on.

Comment: Thanks for stopping by. I used a little trick to deal with 6+/6s+ screen size. I supplied somewhat unusual image sizes: 100x100 for 1x, 200x200 for 2x as expected, but used 390x390 for 3x. I still have to deal with 6/6s. Might just do it by querying UIScreen for it's size.

Answer (score 1):

If your images are photos or raster type images created using a raster drawing tool, then somewhere you will have to scale the original to the sizes you want. You can either do this while running in iOS, or create sets up front using a tool which can give you better scaling results. Unfortunately, the only perfect image will be the original with everything else being a distortion of the truth.

For icons, the only accurate rendering solution is to use vector graphics. Tools like Adobe Illustrator will let you create images which you can scale to different sizes without losing clarity. Unfortunately this still leaves you generating images up front. You can script this generation using most tools and given you said your images were all square, then the total number needed is not huge. At most you need 3 for iPhone (4/5 are same width, 6 and 6+) and 2 for iPad (@1 for mini/ipad1 and @2 for retina).

Although iOS has no direct support I know of for vector image rendering, there are some 3rd party tools. http://www.paintcodeapp.com/ is an example which seems to let you import vector images or draw vector images and then generate image code to run in your app. This kind of tool would give you what you want as the images are now vector drawings drawn at the scale you choose at run time. $99 though.

There is also the SVGKit (https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit), but not sure how good/bad this is. It seems to let you simply load and render direct from SVG files. Might be worth trying.

So in summary, I think you either generate the relatively small subset up front using a tool you can control the output from, take the hit in iOS and let it scale the images or use a 3rd party vector to image rendering kit which would give you what you want.